# Is it possible to remove child from collection and resolve issues on SaveChanges?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, persistence, repository-pattern

We are using Entity Framework Code First with Foreign Key relationships. We investigating on ways on handling removing objects from an entities ICollection in our application.

When we have an entity with child relationships we can add objects directly to their ICollection using Add method. Now when you use remove you get the error

> System.InvalidOperationException occurred Message=The operation
>   failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of
>   the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a
>   relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value.
>   If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship
>   must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another
>   non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

I understand this is because Remove on the collection only deletes the relationship by nulling the foreign key. We wanted to write our business logic in our entity and allow removal.

So get root entity out out of  it's Repostiory e.g Order from OrderRepository then call some specific method of the entity e.g. `Order.AddOrderline(Orderline orderline)` This adds an OrderLine to the Orders `virtual ICollection<OrderLine> OrderLines`

However we can't write code like `Order.CancelOrderline(int orderLineId)` because simply removing from the ICollection causes an error on savings changes.

There doesn't seem to be anyway to achieve this by just manipulating the object collections. Obviously we can remove directly from Context. However I'd like to make it part of the entity. Can we clean up certain entities with no foreign key on SaveChanges event of Entity Framework? Obviously need to tell EF what entities can be removed if they have null foreign key.

We presently are using a repository pattern so the controller doesn't have access to the context. I could obviously use an OrderLine repository or a remove OrderLine method on the Order repository. However just wondering if it was possible to write the code on the entity without references to the persistence mechanism.

Thoughts? Are we going about this all wrong? Do other ORMs allow you to just remove from Child Collections?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I don't know if the following is a solution for you but Entity Framework supports [Identifying Relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/a/762994/270591). In such a relationship the foreign key of the child entity (dependent) to the parent (principal) must be part of the (composite) primary key of the child entity. For example - with `DbContext` data annotations - your model classes have to look like this:

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLine
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Order"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int OrderLineId { get; set; }

    public Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

You can make the `OrderLineId` an autogenerated identity if you want. Important is only that the FK to `Order` is part of the PK.

A code like this for example...

```
using (var ctx = new MyContext())
{
    var order = ctx.Orders.Include("OrderLines").Single(o => o.OrderId == 1);
    var orderLineToDelete = order.OrderLines
        .FirstOrDefault(ol => ol.OrderLineId == 5);
    if (orderLineToDelete != null)
        order.OrderLines.Remove(orderLineToDelete);

    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

...would indeed *delete* the `orderLineToDelete` from the database.

More details are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee373856.aspx) in section "*Considerations for Identifying and Non-identifying Relationships*".

Comment: Ah so if if I make a composite key on the child entities EF will deal with this for me. Now that seems quite attractive.

Comment: That was great but I needed to add  [Key, Column(Order = 0), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int OrderLineId { get; set; } to get it to not complain about identity insert.

Comment: @GraemeMiller: That's what I meant with "*You can make the OrderLineId an autogenerated identity if you want*" :) I forgot to mention that you need to do this in the *model* (with the DatabaseGeneratedOption) *and* in the *database*.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I really like now being able to use remove from the collection as it makes my code far cleaner. It's strange this doesn't seem to get mentioned that often in articles I've read on EF and removing from collections. Plenty of times people just say you can't remove from collection. I will now remember to tell people about this method!

Comment: @GraemeMiller: I agree, it's not very well known. Until 3 months ago I also hadn't heard of it :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571864/in-ef4-1-do-you-have-to-expose-a-foreign-key-property-on-a-dependent-entity-to#comment12136321_9571864

Comment: I have the same problem but I'm not using data annotations. My relationship is specified like this using the fluent api: modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().HasMany(o => o.OrderLines).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(o => o.OrderId). Any suggestions to how I should redefine this relationship to make EF delete the child entity also?

Comment: @Kulvis: That's not possible because your relationship is optional, so your foreign key must allow NULLs. But in an identifying relationship the FK must be part of the PK and you cannot allow NULL in a PK. If the relationship would be required (`WithRequired`) you must define a composite PK for `OrderLine`: `modelBuilder.Entity<OrderLine>().HasKey(ol => new { ol.OrderId, ol.OrderLineId });`.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't know about this! Thanks. I have to say EF is very confusing when it comes to this type of stuff with really poor error messages (hidden in 3 levels of inner exceptions). By the way I had similar problem to @GraemeMiller but I'm fluent, so the solution was: `this.HasKey(c => new { c.ChildPrimaryKey, c.ParentPrimaryKey });` together with `this.Property(c => c.ChildPrimaryKey).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);`

Answer (score 2):

As you're finding, if you just remove an Entity from a collection the Entity hangs around attached to the object context and gives you an error when you call `SaveChanges()`; I've used Domain Events to enable a tidy way of removing the Entity from the object context via a Repository.

I've detailed this approach in my answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360239/ef-code-first-how-are-you-meant-to-delete-a-row-from-an-entitys-collection-whi/8360864#8360864).

Comment: That looks like a really interesting approach. Is it similar to the command pattern? I like the concept of modelling domain events. I really need to actually finish reading my blue book.

Comment: Hmm... not really Command, I don't think - domain events are behaviourless objects which signal something has happened to any objects which handle them. I think I first read about them from [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/DomainEvent.html), but [this article](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation) was the one which really helped me understand how powerful they are :)

Comment: Great that makes sense as they have no payload as you say. Will read up on that. Appreciate the extra references.