# Delete item in database when removed from collection (EF 4.3)

Tags: entity-framework

In my EF4.3 code first (but with an explicitly designed database, as opposed to a database generated by the EF), I have the following problem.

I have an entity "WorkPlan", which can contain one-to-many "Break" entities. In the model, the workplan has an ICollection but the Break does not know about the workplan.

This is an aggregate relationship. A "Break" can not exist outside the scope of a workplan.

What I want to happen is that when I remove a Break from a WorkPlan's collection of breaks, that break should be removed in the database when saving changes:

```
[Test]
public void ShouldRemoveBreakInDatabase()
{
    // Setup
    var workPlan = WorkPlanBuilder.Build(x => x.AddBreak());
    Save(workPlan);

    // Exercise
    var exerciseContext = CreateDataContext();
    workPlan = exerciseContext.WorkPlans.Single();
    workPlan.RemoveBreak(workPlan.Breaks.Single());
    exerciseContext.SaveChanges();

    // Verify            
    var actual = SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar("select count(*) from Breaks");
    Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(0));
}
```

However, the SaveChanges() call results in the following exception:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException : An error
>   occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key
>   properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will
>   return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source
>   of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made
>   easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See
>   the InnerException for details.
>   ----> System.Data.UpdateException :
>   An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception
>   for details.
>   ----> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Cannot
>   insert the value NULL into column 'WorkPlan_Id', table
>   'ActivityStore.dbo.Breaks'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.

It seems clear that when removing the Break from the WorkPlan's collection, EF assumes that it should set the WorkPlan_Id field to null in the database, but the field is not nullable.

Adding the following to my data context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<WorkPlan>().HasMany(x => x.Breaks).WithRequired();
}
```

Causes a different exception:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException : An error
>   occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key
>   properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will
>   return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source
>   of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made
>   easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See
>   the InnerException for details.
>   ----> System.Data.UpdateException :
>   A relationship from the 'WorkPlan_Breaks' AssociationSet is in the
>   'Deleted' state. Given multiplicity constraints, a corresponding
>   'WorkPlan_Breaks_Target' must also in the 'Deleted' state.

Is there an easy way for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I did come up with a solution. But I would prefer something that was pure configuration over this.

But it is at least isolated to my DataContext implementation:

```
    private DbSet<WorkPlan> _workPlans;
    public DbSet<WorkPlan> WorkPlans
    {
        get { return _workPlans; }
        set 
        { 
            _workPlans = value;
            _workPlans.Local.CollectionChanged += LocalWorkPlansChanged;
        }
    }

    private void LocalWorkPlansChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action != NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            return;

        foreach (var workPlan in e.NewItems.Cast<WorkPlan>())
        {
            var collection = workPlan.Breaks as EntityCollection<Break>;
            if (collection == null)
                continue;
            collection.AssociationChanged += WorkPlanBreaksAssociationChanged;
        }
    }

    private void WorkPlanBreaksAssociationChanged(object sender, CollectionChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == CollectionChangeAction.Remove)
        {
            var @break = (Break)e.Element;
            Breaks.Remove(@break);
        }
    }
```

So,

Step 1: Hook up on the event that gets raised whenever the DbSet's in-memory collection of WorkPlans change.

Step 2: Figure out if the WorkPlan change is because of a new object. This could mean a newly instantiated object, or one loaded from the data store.

Step 3: Look at the WorkPlan.Breaks collection for added object. If the collection is an EntityCollection<>, then the object was loaded from the database. Hook up the AssociationChanged event to get notified when the association changes.

Step 4: When an association change event is received, check if it as "Remove" event, and if so, explicitly remove the Break from the Breaks DbSet.

Simpler solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after 1.5-hour googling I found the solution.
The key to accomplishing such task is so called "Identifying relationship". Those are the way to tell EF that entity only "lives" as a child of some other entity, so removing it from its parent should also remove it from database. See related questions:

- [Is it possible to remove child from collection and resolve issues on SaveChanges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033348/is-it-possible-to-remove-child-from-collection-and-resolve-issues-on-savechanges)
  (I would actually mark this as duplicate, but I do not know how :) )
- [What's the difference between identifying and non-identifying relationships?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762937/whats-the-difference-between-identifying-and-non-identifying-relationships/762994#762994)

To sum up, my solution looked like this:

```
public class Item
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Key, ForeignKey("Group"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public ItemGroup Group { get; set; }
}

public class ItemGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

In the database Item.Id is and identity column, GroupId is a foreign key (I do not generate db automatically with EF).