# Entity Framework: removing entity when One-to-One PK association is specified

Tags: entity-framework

I have existing DB with the following structure:
[image]

I'm using EF fluent API to configure relationships between tables:

```
public GroupEntityConfiguration()
{
    HasMany(x => x.Employees).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(x => x.GroupId).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}

public EmployeeEntityConfiguration()
{            
    HasOptional(x => x.InnerGroupMember).WithRequired();
}
```

With this configuration applied I can add new Employee, new InnerGroupMember or fetch data. The problem appears when I try to remove Employee. Then I get an exception:

> The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

As far as I understand above exception is connected with GroupId foreign key. Trying to fix it I'm adding following line to EmployeeEntityConfiguration:

```
HasKey(x => new { x.Id, x.GroupId});
```

But after adding it I get another exception which I believe is connected with InnerGroupMember object:

> Invalid column name 'Guest_Id'. Invalid column name 'Guest_GroupId'.

If I comment out InnerGroupMember navigation property and remove it's configuration, Employee can be removed.

Could you please give me a hint what I'm doing wrong and how to configure entities to be able to perform all needed operations? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an existing Group entity and I want to remove Employee from the Employees Group collection:

```
var group = groupRepository.Find(groupId);
group.RemoveEmployee(employeeId);
_unitOfWork.Save();
```

RemoveEmployee function inside Group entity looks like this:

```
public void RemoveEmployee(int employeeId)
{
    var employee = Employees.Single(n => n.Id == employeeId);
    Employees.Remove(employee);
}
```

That's why I get an exeption:

> The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable....

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033348/is-it-possible-to-remove-child-from-collection-and-resolve-issues-on-savechanges) I wanted to fix it adding `HasKey(x => new { x.Id, x.GroupId});` function inside EmployeeEntityConfiguration what leads to the second exception:

> Invalid column name 'Guest_Id'. Invalid column name 'Guest_GroupId'.

Actually I made this step (I mean adding HasKey function) without changing DB structure. To make it work, inside Employees table I have to create composite key - combination of Id and GroupId which is also a foreign key. This modification forces changes inside InnerGroupMembers table. DB structure looks now as following:
[image]

Now I'm able to remove Employee in a way I showed at the beginning.

Anyway I'm not going for this solution. They are different ways to achieve what I want. Here are some links:

- [Removing entity from a Related Collection](http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2010/07/23/removing-entity-from-a-related-collection.aspx)
- [Delete Dependent Entities When Removed From EF Collection](http://www.phdesign.com.au/programming/delete-dependent-entities-when-removed-from-ef-collection/)
- [The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the
  foreign-key properties is non-nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538974/the-relationship-could-not-be-changed-because-one-or-more-of-the-foreign-key-pro)

Answer (score 0):

For one-to-one relationships cascading delete is not enabled by default, even not for required relationships (as it is the case for required one-to-many relationships, that is: The `WillCascadeOnDelete(true)` in your one-to-many mapping is redundant). You must define cascading delete for a one-to-one relationship always explicitly:

```
HasOptional(x => x.InnerGroupMember).WithRequired().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

When you delete an `Employee` now, the database will delete the related `InnerGroupMember` as well and the exception should disappear.

Comment: It does not work. I think that before adding HasKey method to configuration, exception I get is connected with Employee entity and GuestId foreign key. But I don't know what I should do to get rid of it and still be able to perform different actions like get data, update data, etc.

Comment: Sorry, not GuestId but of course GroupId. Anyway I think I know what I did wrong. Please see my answer below.

Comment: @rwasik: OK, then I misinterpreted the statement in your question "*The problem appears when I try to remove Employee*". I thought you wanted to delete the `Employee` from the database. But you actually only want to remove the *relationship* between `Employee` and the `Group`.