# How can i delete a child record in a one-to-many relationship with Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, parent-child

this question has been discussed/asked a lot of times but i still can't find a conclusive answer to this problem. I apologize in advanced for the lengthy explanation and it means so much to me that you take the time to read it and understand my problem.

I am developing a parking lot management system for a multi-floored commercial business entity based on reservations, in which clients call the administrator of the system and they let them know at what date and span of time they would like to have a parking lot available to them.

For somebody to register a new parking lot in the system, they first have to register and select a floor. So there is a one-to-many relationship between floors and parking lots. One floor can have many parking lots. This is how my classes are implemented:

**Floor class**

```
public class Nivel
{
    #region Campos

    int _IdNivel;

    #endregion

    #region Propiedades

    public int IdNivel
    {
        get
        {
            return _IdNivel;
        }

        private set
        {
            _IdNivel = value;
        }
    }

    public string NombreNivel { get; set; }
    public int CantidadParqueos { get; set; }
    public List<Parqueo> Parqueos { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructores

    public Nivel()
    {
        Parqueos = new List<Parqueo>();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**Parking lot class**

```
public class Parqueo
{
    #region Campos

    int _IdParqueo;
    int _IdNivel;

    #endregion

    #region Propiedades

    public int IdParqueo
    {
        get
        {
            return _IdParqueo;
        }

        private set
        {
            _IdParqueo = value;
        }
    }

    public int IdNivel
    {
        get
        {
            return _IdNivel;
        }
        private set
        {
            _IdNivel = value;
        }
    }

    public string NombreParqueo { get; set; }
    public string EstadoParqueo { get; set; }
    public Nivel Nivel { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructores

    public Parqueo()
    {

    }

    public Parqueo(string NombreParqueo, string EstadoParqueo)
    {            
        this.NombreParqueo = NombreParqueo;
        this.EstadoParqueo = EstadoParqueo;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Now all this is working fine and dandy. My main issue, as the title says, has to do with deleting a specific parking lot on a given floor. I have this worked out, but i want a more elegant solution than the one i already have. This is what i have in my form load event for the parking lot registration form:

```
    private void FrmRegistroParqueos_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.groupBox3.Left = (this.Parent.Width / 2) - (this.groupBox3.Width / 2);
        this.groupBox3.Top = (this.Parent.Height / 2) - (this.groupBox3.Height / 2);            

        contexto.Niveles.Include("Parqueos").Load();            

        bindingSourceNiveles.DataSource = contexto.Niveles.Local.ToBindingList<Nivel>();

        bindingSourceParqueos.DataSource = bindingSourceNiveles;

        bindingSourceParqueos.DataMember = "Parqueos";

        this.DgvNiveles.DataSource = bindingSourceNiveles;
        this.DgvParqueos.DataSource = bindingSourceParqueos;            

        if (this.DgvNiveles.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            this.DgvNiveles.ClearSelection();
        }
    }
```

In short, this is what i am doing: i am instantiating the context, as well as two binding sources, so that i can implement a master/detail form with two datagridviews so that selecting a particular floor on one of the datagridviews populates the other datagridview with the parking lots available on that selected floor. Then, i run a query on the context so that i can load all the floors available in my database in local memory including the parking lots in order to populate the binding sources and reflect the information over to the datagridviews.

This here is my code for deleting a selected parking lot:

```
    private void BtnEliminarParqueo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Nivel)bindingSourceNiveles.Current).CantidadParqueos -= 1;

        bindingSourceNiveles.ResetCurrentItem();            

        Parqueo parqueoEliminado = new Parqueo();

        parqueoEliminado = (Parqueo)bindingSourceParqueos.Current;

        bindingSourceParqueos.RemoveCurrent();

        contexto.Parqueos.Remove(parqueoEliminado);

        contexto.SaveChanges();
    }
```

A little background information that you, if are knowledgeable about the Entity Framework, already know. Deleting a related child object from one of the navigation object collections doesn't actually delete that object from the database: it just deletes the relationship between the parent and the child. Now, the relationship that is established between a floor and a parking lot, in my code, is a strict one - you can't add a parking lot without having it related to a specific floor. That means the foreign key in the parking lot's table is non-nullable. So, deleting a specific parking lot in my program by removing it from the floor's parking lot collection violates this rule and then the context throws an exception saying that i tried to set a null to the foreign key when calling the method SaveChanges on the context.

Due to this cumbersome behavior, i tried one workaround before arriving at my solution: if the Entity Framework won't let me delete a child object via the objects in my program then i would remove it by deleting it from the context itself so that then the changes are reflected back to my parking lots' datagridview and the user can see that the parking lot was indeed removed. Now, this approach "works" in the sense that it indeed does remove the child record from the database, but then the parking lot datagridview throws an index out-of-bounds exception saying that there is nothing at the position where the deleted parking lot was. Here is a pic of the exception, i apologize for not being able to insert the picture here (I don't have enough reputation points and this is my first time asking a question here):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vank28utf7bpzdg/Exception.png?m

And the code for this failed work-around that gives me the nasty exception (which by the way fires more than 3 times after clicking the ok button on the messagebox):

```
    private void BtnEliminarParqueo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Nivel)bindingSourceNiveles.Current).CantidadParqueos -= 1;

        bindingSourceNiveles.ResetCurrentItem();            

        contexto.Parqueos.Remove((Parqueo)bindingSourceParqueos.Current);

        contexto.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Though it failed, this is what i wanted to implement in my program and, in my opinion, the way things should work. Deleting the currently selected object by way of the object collection and have it reflect back to the database or deleting the child record from the database and have it reflect back the changes to the datagridviews - that is what i wanted. But none of that works, the first solution doesn't work because i can't have a null value in my foreign key and the second one because of the exception the datagridview throws. I just want to be able to delete a record in my datagridview in a way that the user can actually see in the datagridview was deleted and also deleting it from the database.

So then i arrived at my current solution:

**1** - Instantiate a new parking lot

**2** - Set it to the currently selected parking lot on the parking lot datagridview

**3** - Remove the currently selected object via the parking lot's bindingsource RemoveCurrent() method so that the user can see that the parking lot was removed from the datagridview. By this time, the relationship is set to be deleted on the context by setting this object's foreign key property to null

**4** - Remove the deleted record from the database via the context's Remove() method

**5** - Call the SaveChanges() method on the context so that the child record is deleted from the database

Basically what i am doing is deleting the object two times, once so that the user can see that the parking lot was removed in the datagridview and one more time to delete the unrelated child object (null foreign key) from the database. This way i can keep the context from complaining that the child record has a null foreign key when i call SaveChanges.

In my eyes this is an ugly solution to the problem, and i would like some feedback on any other approach you may have about this. Thank you in advance for taking the time to read this lenghty wall of text and i apologize for being so verbosed, but i felt that it was necessary to understand exactly what is going on.

Have a good day guys.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making the one-to-many relationship an *identifying relationship*. You do this by including the foreign key `Parqueo.IdNivel` from `Parqueo` to `Nivel` into the primary key. The primary key of `Parqueo` becomes a composite key then consisting of `(IdParqueo, IdNivel)`.

The clue is that in an identifying relationship in order to delete the dependent item you just need to remove the `Parqueo` from the `Nivel.Parqueos` collection. When you call `SaveChanges` the removed `Parqueo` will be deleted from the database automatically, thus avoiding the foreign key constraint violation. You don't have to call `contexto.Parqueos.Remove(parqueo)` to delete it from the database.

More details about identifying relationships and an example are here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11033988/270591

Comment: Thank you Slauma for your info. I had already seen and tried to apply an identifying relationship for my model but i am getting errors. I am not sure how to implement this.