# Replace related entities with new not working when assigning a list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, collections

Let's say I've got an entity `Student` and it has related entities `Classes`.

I need logic to assign new `Classes` that would replace existing `Classes`

I'm using Entity Framework, and these classes are mapped to a database, so when `DbContext.SaveChanges()` is executed, it should replace old records with the new ones.

Here is sort of a pseudo code for this - the version with `AddRange()` works, but version with `Classes = NewClasses.ToList();` - adds new classes but does not remove the old ones.

Can anyone explain why just assigning a list is not removing the old records?

```
public class Student 
{
    public List<Class> Classes { get; set;}

    public void UpdateClassesA(ICollection<Class> newClasses)
    {
        //this just adds new classes, but doesn't remove the existing ones (when EF SaveChanges is performed)
        Classes = newClasses.ToList();
    }

    public void UpdateClassesB(ICollection<Class> newClasses)
    {
        Classes = new List<Class>();
        Classes.AddRange(newClasses);
    }
}
```

Comment: This helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116199/entity-framework-proper-way-to-replace-collection-in-one-to-many

Comment: I have loaded the related collection with `Include(x => x.Classes)` but somehow that was not enough in my case